# Why isn't Raku Ichijou's mother's face ever revealed in the manga?

Tags: nisekoi

Why isn't Raku Ichijou's mother's face ever revealed in the manga?

I mean, the manga ended, and she was the last character introduced in the series. What was the need to hide her face then?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three reasons to obscure or hide a character's face in a story.

1. Hazy memory. Another character's memory of this person is unclear, so their face is not shown. This has actually been done in *Nisekoi* and is actually a major driving point of the plot, since Raku Ichijo can't remember the face of the girl he made the promise to. In flashbacks, the girl is depicted without showing her face.
2. Focus. This character is not the current focus of the story, so their face is not shown. I saw a good example of this in the *Watamote* anime, at the end of episode 8. When Kii-Chan is going home, she is in the car with her mother, but her mother's face is not shown. The focus is on Kii-Chan sharing her experiences for the day, and her mother is just there so she has someone to talk to. Her mother is not the focus of the story.
3. Veneration. The character is too important to show, or showing them might somehow reduce their mystique. For historical or religious figures, one might not want to show their face in order to glorify them. For instance, figures like Saint Anselm, Oda Nobunaga, and the Buddha might have their faces obscured to show that they are too great to be depicted.

I suspect the case of Ichijo's mother is a combination of all three.

1. As previously mentioned, *Nisekoi* made extensive use of hazy memory in it's story. It's unclear what exactly Ichijo's relationship with his mother is like, but given she doesn't appear in most of the story, it's possible Ichijo hasn't seen her in a long time, and thus his memory of her is hazy. Likewise, the other characters haven't seen her in a long time, if at all, and thus her face is not depicted in flashbacks.
2. The focus on the scene where she returns may be more on the information Chitoge is getting from Raku's mother rather than his mother herself. The character is less important than the revelations she's sharing and Chitoge's reactions to these revelations.
3. The veneration point, I think, is the most important one here. Ichijo's mother is the author of the *Zawze in Love* children's novel, which is so important throughout the series. This book has almost mythic importance to the children, and they act out the events in the book through the keys and locket they have. As the author of this book, Raku's mother is a highly important person. Depicting her may lead to disappointment, as she would lose some of her mystique, and that in turn could make the children's book lose mystique. In order to maintain the mystique around her, and thus preserve the mystique of the *Zawze in Love* story, the author decided not to depict her appearance.

As mentioned in the other answer, a character's face might also not be shown due to constraints. Designing a character takes some time and effort. Shortcuts might be made for less important characters and background characters to get the manga out on time. I personally don't think this is the case for Ichijo's mother, but it is a point worth considering.

Though not related to *Nisekoi*, here's a quotation from the author of *A Silent Voice*, Yoshitoki Oima, on choosing not to draw the face of a different character, which will give a little insight on why sometimes characters' faces aren't drawn in.

> Her face doesn't appear in the manga because I thought that would make her character stand out more. Once you draw a character's face and expressions, that takes on a certain meaning and it affects the story.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because she wasn't integral to the story in any manner.

For instance we only see Midoriya's mother in My Hero Academia there is no mention of his father except in some throwaway scenes.

It may be due to the fact that drawing Manga is a tedious job and author might want to keep his work as easy as possible and it's much simpler by minimising the characters introduced.

Comment: You do realise that in the manga we see the entire body except for the face. And Chitoge meets her in person. She is pretty much integral to the story.

Comment: @Ashray I haven't read the entire manga so I can't comment on that but this was a probable reason I could come up with